# I got an error when I use sqlx transaction,tx.NamedQuery()

Tags: go, sqlx

I got an error when I use sqlx transaction,tx.NamedQuery() to run a transaction with postgresql.
Sometimes I need the first sql's returning id to execute the other sql, so I used tx.NamedQuery not tx.NamedExec(). The code works correctly if I use tx.NamedExec().

Here is the code, thank you

`

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq" // PostgreSQL
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    Id   int           `json:"id" db:"id" form:"id"`
    Name string        `json:"name" db:"name" form:"name"`
    Role pq.Int64Array `json:"role" db:"role" form:"role"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=postgres password=*** dbname=*** sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(1)
    tx, err := db.Beginx()
    test := Test{Name: "name", Role: []int64{1, 2, 3}}
    _, err1 := tx.NamedQuery(`INSERT  INTO test(name,role) VALUES (:name,:role)returning id`, test)
    fmt.Println(err1)
    _, err1 = tx.NamedQuery(`INSERT  INTO test(name,role) VALUES (:name,:role)returning id`, test)
    fmt.Println(err1)
    _, err1 = tx.NamedQuery(`INSERT  INTO test(name,role) VALUES (:name,:role)returning id`, test)
    fmt.Println(err1)
    _, err1 = tx.NamedQuery(`INSERT  INTO test(name,role) VALUES (:name,:role)returning id`, test)
    fmt.Println(err1)
    _, err1 = tx.NamedQuery(`INSERT  INTO test(name,role) VALUES (:name,:role)returning id`, test)
    fmt.Println(err1)
    tx.Commit()
}
```

`

output:

```
   <nil>
pq: unexpected Parse response 'D'
driver: bad connection
driver: bad connection
driver: bad connection

Process finished with exit code 0
```